# Must one give notice?

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, employment

The custom in the United States is that, whenever feasible, an [at-will](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At-will_employment) employee is given two weeks' [notice](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/notice#Noun) when fired (except when fired for cause) and gives two weeks' notice when quitting a job. (Many jobs have longer or shorter customary notice periods, but two weeks is the general standard.)

Does *halacha* have anything to say about giving notice? Specifically, is there any requirement for an employer or employee to give advance notice? Under what circumstances, and how much notice?

---

Please exclude/ignore any considerations that arise as corollaries of, for example, "one must follow one's host country's laws" or "all contracts are entered into with local custom implicitly stipulated" or "it'd cause a *chilul Hashem*". I'm looking for original-to-*halacha* considerations specifically about giving notice, not considerations that are only because of secondary concerns.

Comment: disusses quitting jobs (skip first 9 minutes or so) http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/796096/Rabbi_Yona_Reiss/Halachic_Issues_of_Teachers-_Mechanchim-_and_Schools_in_the_Job_Market

Comment: These employees are _poalim_ or _kablanim_? (Or are you purposefully being inspecific?)

Comment: @DoubleAA: Beats me: you'll have to define those terms for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The רמב"ם in [הלכות שכירות פרק ט](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/d109.htm) says that a worker can walk out in the middle of the day, as we are slaves to Hashem and cannot be enslaved by an employer.

> א...אם התחיל הפועל במלאכה, וחזר בו בחצי היום--חוזר:  שנאמר "כי לי בני ישראל, עבדים--עבדיי הם" (ויקרא כה,נה), ולא עבדים לעבדים.‏

The רמב"ם then goes on to describe the consequences of walking out:

> ט  וכיצד דין הפועל שחזר בו אחר שהתחיל--שמין לו מה שעשה, ונוטל. 
>       ואם קבלן הוא, שמין לו מה שעתיד לעשות:
>       בין שהוזילו לו בעת ששכרן, בין לא הוזילו, בין שהוזלה המלאכה אחר כן, 
>       בין לא הוזלה--שמין לו מה שעתיד לעשות.‏

A worker who walked out of the job in the middle of the day gets paid for the amount of work he already did. (So he does not get punished/penalized for not finishing the job).

If, however, he is a Kablan (agreed to do the entire job), he gets the *unfinished part of the job* deducted from his salary; irrelevant of whether this is to his benefit or detriment.

The רמבם then goes on to give examples. (translations from here onwards copied from [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1368672/jewish/Chapter-9.htm).)

> י  כיצד:  קיבל ממנו קמה לקצור בשתי סלעים, קצר חצייה והניח חצייה, בגד לארוג בשתי סלעים, ארג חצייו והניח חצייו--שמין להן מה שעתיד לעשות.  אם היה שווה שישה דינרין--נותן לו שקל, או יגמרו את מלאכתן.  ואם היה הנשאר יפה שני דינרין--אינו נותן להן אלא סלע, שהרי לא עשו אלא חצי מלאכה.‏

What is implied? A person agreed to harvest standing grain for two Selaim. He harvested half of the grain, but left half unharvested. Similarly, a person agreed to weave a garment for two Selaim. He wove half of the garment, but left half unwoven. If the remainder would cost six Dinarim to complete, the original contractor is paid a shekel or he is given the option of completing his work. If the remainder was worth only two Dinarim, the owner need not pay the contractor more than a Sela, because he did not perform more than half the work.

> יא  במה דברים אמורים, בדבר שאינו אבוד.  אבל בדבר האבוד--כגון פשתנו לעלות מן המשרה, או ששכר חמור להביא חלילין למת או לכלה וכל כיוצא בהן--אחד פועל ואחד קבלן, אינו יכול לחזור בו אלא אם כן נאנס, כגון שחלה, או שמע שמת לו מת.  ואם לא נאנס, וחזר בו--שוכר עליהן או מטען.‏

When does the above apply? With regard to work that does not involve an immediate loss.

If, however, the work involves an immediate loss - e.g., he hired the workers to remove flax from the vat, or he hired a donkey to bring flutes for a funeral or for a wedding or the like - neither a worker nor a contractor may retract unless he is held back by forces beyond his control -e.g., he became ill or a close relative died.

If the worker is not held back by forces beyond his control, and he retracts, the owner may hire others on their account or deceive them.

> יב  כיצד מטען:  אומר להם סלע קצצתי לכם, בואו וטלו שתיים, עד שיגמרו מלאכתן; ולא ייתן להם אלא מה שפסק תחילה.  ואפילו נתן להם השתיים, מחזיר מהן התוספת.‏

What is meant by deceiving them? He tells them: "I agreed to pay you a Sela; take two so that you will complete your work." Afterwards, he is not required to give them anything more than he originally agreed. Moreover, even if he gave them two, he can compel them to return the additional amount.

> יג  כיצד שוכר עליהן:  שוכר פועלים אחרים, וגומרים מלאכתן שלא תאבד; וכל שיוסיף לאלו הפועלין האחרים על מה שפסק לראשונים, נוטל מן הראשונים.  ועד כמה, עד כדי שכרן של ראשונים.  ואם היה להם ממון תחת ידו--שוכר להשלים המלאכה עד ארבעים חמישים זוז בכל יום לכל פועל, אף על פי ששכר הפועל שלוש או ארבע.  במה דברים אמורים, בזמן שאין שם פועלים לשכור בשכרן להשלים המלאכה.  אבל אם יש שם פועלים לשכור בשכרן, ואמרו לו צא ושכור מאלו והשלם מלאכתך ולא תאבד--בין שוכר בין קבלן--אין לו עליהן אלא תרעומת; ושמין לשוכר מה שעשה, ולקבלן מה שעתיד לעשות.‏

What is meant by hiring others on their account? He hires other workers who complete their task so that he will not suffer a loss. Whatever he must add to pay these later workers beyond the amount the first workers agreed upon, he may take from the first workers.

To what extent are the first workers responsible? For their entire wage. Moreover, if they have property that is in the employer's possession, the employer can use that property to hire workers to complete their work until he pays each worker 40 or 50 Zuz a day although he originally hired the worker at three or four Zuz.

When does the above apply? When there are no workers available to hire at the wage to be paid the original workers. If, however, such workers are available and the original workers tell the employer: "Go out and hire from these to complete your work so that you will not suffer a loss," whether a worker or a contractor is involved, the employer has only complaints against them.

To determine the wage that should be paid, we follow these guidelines: For a worker, we calculate the work he already performed and for a contractor, we calculate the work that must be performed.

Comment: This doesn't deal with what kind of damages he may have to pay if he chooses to leave early.

Comment: I'll second @DoubleAA's comment, but +1: it does answer my question technically. Not that I ever doubted one can walk out (and pay damages).

Comment: @msh210 - I've added some more info

Comment: (Consider utilizing a free English translation of the Yad: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/682956/jewish/Mishneh-Torah.htm )

Answer (score 2):

The Talmud's treatment of laborers usually involved relatively unskilled day labor, or someone paid to do a specific job (e.g. build a house).

In today's professional job market, where it takes quite a while for someone to find a job, as well as for a company to hire an employee, I would think that an argument could be made to draw a parallel from real-estate rentals, at least in the spirit of the law.

*Baruch sheKivanti* -- the Chazon Ish says this exactly, as heard in [a yutorah.org lecture from Rabbi Reiss on employment issues](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/888928/rabbi-yona-reiss/from-the-dayan-s-desk-20-termination-employment-disputes-part-2-severance-notice-and-grounds-for-termination/).

Rambam, laws of rentals Ch. 6:

> ו,ז  המשכיר בית לחברו סתם--אינו יכול להוציאו, עד שיודיעו שלושים יום מקודם, כדי לבקש מקום, ולא יהיה מושלך בדרך; ולסוף השלושים, ייצא.
> ו,ח  במה דברים אמורים, בימות החמה; אבל בימות הגשמים, אינו יכול להוציאו מן החג ועד הפסח.  קבע לו שלושים יום לפני החג--אם נשאר מן השלושים אפילו יום אחד לאחר החג, אינו יכול להוציאו עד מוצאי הפסח:  והוא, שיודיעו שלושים יום מקודם.  במה דברים אמורים, בעיירות; אבל בכרכים--אחד ימות החמה ואחד ימות הגשמים, צריך להודיעו שנים עשר חודש מקודם.  וכן בחנות--בין בכרכים בין בעיירות, צריך להודיעו שנים עשר חודש מקודם.
> ו,ט  [ח] כשם שהמשכיר חייב להודיעו--כך השוכר חייב להודיעו מקודם שלושים יום בעיירות, או מקודם שנים עשר חודש בכרכים, כדי שיבקש שכן, ולא יישאר ביתו פנוי.  ואם לא הודיעו--אינו יכול לצאת, אלא ייתן השכר.

> One who rents a house to someone without specifying terms may not evict him without thirty days' notice, to give the tenant time to find another place and not be left out on the street ... [additional notice may be necessary in the wintertime, when the housing-rental market was particularly bad; or in a major metropolis]. Similarly with regards to stores, regardless of location, an advance notice of twelve months is necessary. [The Mishna Bava Metzia 8:6 even discusses greater notifications for facilities requiring a lot of investment/construction, such as bakeries or dye shops.] And just as the landlord must inform the tenant, the tenant must give corresponding advance notice to the landlord ... so the landlord may find a new tenant and not have his property left empty.

Comment: Good point. But how do you explain the Rambam's introduction to these Halachot: "we are slaves to Hashem and cannot be enslaved by an employer."