# May an employer dismiss an employee to pressure him in a non–work-related matter

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, employment, current-events

Without discussing whether the particular case currently in the news actually qualifies as the situation I’m describing, consider the following case:

In his private life, an employee of mine is engaged in behavior I believe to be wrong. There is nothing in this matter that relates to me or my business. (Ignore public pressure put on me; or assume the public knows nothing about this case. Assume also this is not legally-protected wrongful behavior, *vehameivin yovin*.)

Am I permitted under *halachah* to suspend or fire this employee as a coercive strategy? (He will not easily find work elsewhere.)

Somewhat related: *[Must one give notice?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30708/70)*

Comment: Is this different from simply asking whether you can fire an employee without cause?

Comment: It actually assumes one cannot, at least not without suitable notice. This assumption may not be well-founded, I admit.